# How to import client authorization settings into Keycloak REALM through REST?

Tags: python, rest, import, realm, keycloak

I am trying to import a client and its authorization settings into my current Realm "TestRealm" using the REST API of the Keycloak version 15 via my Python script.
My client representation is a JSON dump of another Keycloak REALM of mine, so I know that the values and structure is correct.
Here is a snippet of my code, how I try to import the client and its authorization settings:

```py
class KeycloakClient:
  def __init__(self, base_url, admin_username, admin_password, verify=True):
    self.keycloak_base = base_url
    self.admin_username = admin_username
    self.admin_password = admin_password
    self.current_access_token = None
    self.verify = verify

  @property
  def token(self):
    if not self.current_access_token or self.is_token_expired():
      # implemented elsewhere
      self.refresh_access_token()
    return self.current_access_token

  def post(self, path, data):
    headers = {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + self.token,
      'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
    }
    return requests.post(f"{self.keycloak_base}/{path}", data=data, headers=headers, verify=self.verify)

  def create_client(self, realmName, clientData):
    return self.post(f"admin/realms/{realmName}/clients", data=clientData)
    
keycloak_client = KeycloakClient("127.0.0.1:8080", "admin", "pass!")

client_file = open("single_client.json", "r")
new_client = client_file.read()

keycloak_client.create_client("TestRealm", new_client)
```

The client representation inside "single_client.json" looks like this:

```json
{
"id" : "586fcea1-9049-47a0-af14-9e09d660a728",
"clientId" : "Test-Client",
"name" : "Test-Client-New",
"surrogateAuthRequired" : false,
"enabled" : true,
"alwaysDisplayInConsole" : false,
"clientAuthenticatorType" : "client-secret",
"secret" : "5123feeb-8754-49bf-b98a-2d5411bb53b",
"authorizationSettings" : {
  "allowRemoteResourceManagement" : true,
  "policyEnforcementMode" : "ENFORCING",
  "resources" : [ {
    "name" : "Dialog.Systeminformation.OS",
    "ownerManagedAccess" : false,
    "displayName" : "System Information OS",
    "attributes" : {
      "Description" : [ "View all OS" ]
    },
    "_id" : "0afa876b-7f22-4ecd-8393-4101dc6dc89e",
    "uris" : [ ],
    "scopes" : [ {
      "name" : "visible"
    } ]
  }, {
    "name" : "View.Data.ViewerClasses",
    "ownerManagedAccess" : false,
    "displayName" : "Data ViewerClasses",
    "attributes" : {
      "Description" : [ "View/edit viwer class data" ]
    },
    "_id" : "0d08ea97-4a61-4b9f-9b97-3bc1c87fe5e4",
    "uris" : [ ],
    "scopes" : [ {
      "name" : "visible"
    }, {
      "name" : "editable"
    } ]
  } ]
}
```

After executing this script I can see the fully imported client inside the Keycloak UI, with the exception of the authorization settings.

NOTE:
The same problem occurs when I try to update an existing clint using the PUT endpoint for clients. I have tried this with different clients but always end up without the authorization settings being imported or updated.

Am I using the API in a wrong way or is this behavior intended? What other ways exist to import client authorization settings separately from the REALM.
IF there maybe is a better way to update my realm or if I missed out on an endpoint I would be happy for recommendations.

NOTE 2:
The overall goal of the intended import is to update a REALM, but keep user/group/parts of the authorization settings.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What does this question have to do with Realm - part of MongoDB Realm the database? It's tagged with Realm but I don't see a correlation.

Answer (score 2):

You missed one item in yours client.json file.

you needs to add "serviceAccountsEnabled": true,

This JSON works at Keycloak v18.0.0

```
{
    "id": "586fcea1-9049-47a0-af14-9e09d660a728",
    "clientId": "Test-Client",
    "name": "Test-Client-New",
    "surrogateAuthRequired": false,
    "enabled": true,
    "alwaysDisplayInConsole": false,
    "clientAuthenticatorType": "client-secret",
    "secret": "5123feeb-8754-49bf-b98a-2d5411bb53b",
    "redirectUris": [],
    "webOrigins": [],
    "notBefore": 0,
    "bearerOnly": false,
    "consentRequired": false,
    "standardFlowEnabled": true,
    "implicitFlowEnabled": false,
    "directAccessGrantsEnabled": false,
    "serviceAccountsEnabled": true,
    "publicClient": false,
    "frontchannelLogout": false,
    "protocol": "openid-connect",
    "attributes": {},
    "authenticationFlowBindingOverrides": {},
    "fullScopeAllowed": true,
    "nodeReRegistrationTimeout": -1,
    "authorizationSettings": {
        "allowRemoteResourceManagement": true,
        "policyEnforcementMode": "ENFORCING",
        "resources": [
            {
                "name": "Dialog.Systeminformation.OS",
                "ownerManagedAccess": false,
                "displayName": "System Information OS",
                "attributes": {},
                "uris": [],
                "scopes": [
                    {
                        "name": "visible"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "View.Data.ViewerClasses",
                "ownerManagedAccess": false,
                "displayName": "Data ViewerClasses",
                "attributes": {},
                "uris": [],
                "scopes": [
                    {
                        "name": "visible"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "editable"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "scopes": [
            {
                "name": "visible"
            },
            {
                "name": "editable"
            }
        ],
        "decisionStrategy": "UNANIMOUS"
    }
}
```

This posted screen capture in Postmen after add client POST call.
[image]

This is Added Client screen in Keycloak after call API.
Keycloak returned 201 Created status without error.
You can see added new resources with scopes in client's Authorization tab.
[image]