# Keycloak: provide scope depending on the group

Tags: keycloak

What I want to do is to configure the following feature on Keycloak:

- my client has scope **profile**
- user A is on group **A** configured with scope **groupa**
- user B is on group **B** configured with scope **groupb**

When user A is logging in, he will have a scope claim with **profile groupa** and for user B, he will have **profile groupb**.
It seems possible for role claim, but I didn’t found how to achieve this for scope claim.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

User's access token only includes realm roles not it's scope.

If you want to user's mapping scope, have to call extra REST API calls.

##### Overview

[image]

##### Demo

I am using Keycloak V21 for the demo

##### UI setting

```
Launching Keycloak V21 by docker compose 

#1 Create `my-realm`

#2 Create realm roles `role::group_a` and `role::group_b`

#3 Create client scopes `scope::group_a` and `scope::group_b` with Optional Assigned type
   to assign role
   `scope::group_a` -> `role::group_a` and `scope::group_b` -> `role::group_b`

#4 Create `my-client`
   Web origins 
   http://localhost:8080/realms/my-realm/my-client
   To `Add Client scope` with optional assigned type `scope::group_a` and `scope::group_b`

#5 Create `group_a` and `group_b`

#6 Create `user_a` and `user_b` with joined group
   `user_a` -> `group_a` and `user_b` -> `group_b`
```

UI setting results

#1 `my-realm`

[image]

#2 Create realm roles `role::group_a` and `role::group_b`

[image]

#3 Create client scopes

[image]
[image]
[image]

#4 Create `my-client`

[image]

#5 Create `group_a` and `group_b`
[image]

#6 Create `user_a` and `user_b` with joined group
`user_a` -> `group_a` and `user_b` -> `group_b`

[image]

[image]

##### Get user access token for finding role and client scopes

```js
const axios = require('axios')
const decode = require('jwt-decode');

const getMasterToken = async () => {
    try {
        const resp = await axios.post(
            url = 'http://localhost:8080/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token',
            data = new URLSearchParams({
                'client_id': 'admin-cli',
                'username': 'admin',
                'password': 'admin',
                'grant_type': 'password'
            })
        );
        return resp.data.access_token;
    } catch (err) {
        // Handle Error Here
        console.error(err);
    }
};

const getUserToken = async (user_name, password) => {
    try {
        const resp = await axios.post(
            url = 'http://localhost:8080/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token',
            data = new URLSearchParams({
                'client_id': 'my-client',
                'username': user_name,
                'password': password,
                'grant_type': 'password'
            })
        );
        return resp.data.access_token;
    } catch (err) {
        // Handle Error Here
        console.error(err);
    }
};

const getUserId = async (master_token, user_name) => {
    try {
        const siteUrl = `http://localhost:8080/admin/realms/my-realm/users/?username=${user_name}`
        const response = await axios.get(siteUrl, {
            headers: {
                'Accept-Encoding': 'application/json',
                Authorization: `Bearer ${master_token}`
            }
        });
        return Promise.resolve(response.data[0].id);

    } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
}
const getClientId = async (master_token, client_name) => {
    try {
        const siteUrl = `http://localhost:8080/admin/realms/my-realm/clients/?clientId=${client_name}`
        const response = await axios.get(siteUrl, {
            headers: {
                'Accept-Encoding': 'application/json',
                Authorization: `Bearer ${master_token}`
            }
        });
        return Promise.resolve(response.data[0].id);

    } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
}

const getGroupId = async (master_token, group_name) => {
    try {
        const siteUrl = `http://localhost:8080/admin/realms/my-realm/ui-ext/groups/?name=${group_name}`
        const response = await axios.get(siteUrl, {
            headers: {
                'Accept-Encoding': 'application/json',
                Authorization: `Bearer ${master_token}`
            }
        });
        return Promise.resolve(response.data[0].id);

    } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
}
const getGroupRoleMappings = async (master_token, group_id) => {
    try {
        const siteUrl = `http://localhost:8080/admin/realms/my-realm/groups/${group_id}/role-mappings`
        const response = await axios.get(siteUrl, {
            headers: {
                'Accept-Encoding': 'application/json',
                Authorization: `Bearer ${master_token}`
            }
        });
        return Promise.resolve(response.data);

    } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
}

const getClientOptionalScopes = async (master_token, client_id) => {
    try {
        const siteUrl = `http://localhost:8080/admin/realms/my-realm/clients/${client_id}/optional-client-scopes`
        const response = await axios.get(siteUrl, {
            headers: {
                'Accept-Encoding': 'application/json',
                Authorization: `Bearer ${master_token}`
            }
        });
        return Promise.resolve(response.data);

    } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
}

const getScopesMappings = async (master_token) => {
    try {
        const siteUrl = `http://localhost:8080/admin/realms/my-realm/client-scopes`
        const response = await axios.get(siteUrl, {
            headers: {
                'Accept-Encoding': 'application/json',
                Authorization: `Bearer ${master_token}`
            }
        });
        return Promise.resolve(response.data);

    } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
}

const getScopeMappingGroup = async (master_token, scope_id) => {
    try {
        const siteUrl = `http://localhost:8080/admin/realms/my-realm/client-scopes/${scope_id}/scope-mappings`
        const response = await axios.get(siteUrl, {
            headers: {
                'Accept-Encoding': 'application/json',
                Authorization: `Bearer ${master_token}`
            }
        });
        return Promise.resolve(response.data);

    } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
}

const getClientDefaultScopes = async (master_token, client_id) => {
    try {
        const siteUrl = `http://localhost:8080/admin/realms/my-realm/clients/${client_id}/default-client-scopes`
        const response = await axios.get(siteUrl, {
            headers: {
                'Accept-Encoding': 'application/json',
                Authorization: `Bearer ${master_token}`
            }
        });
        return Promise.resolve(response.data);

    } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
}

(async () => {
    const master_token = await getMasterToken()

    const client_name = 'my-client'
    const client_id = await getClientId(master_token, client_name)
    console.log(client_name +'\'s ' + 'client_id: ' + client_id)

    const user_name = 'user_a'
    const user_id = await getUserId(master_token, user_name)
    console.log(user_name +'\'s ' + 'user_id: ' + user_id)
    
    const user_token = await getUserToken('user_a', '1234')
    console.log('user_token JWT: ' + JSON.stringify(decode(user_token)['realm_access'], null, 4))

    const group_name = 'group_a'
    const group_id = await getGroupId(master_token, 'group_a')
    console.log(group_name +'\'s ' + 'group_id: ' + group_id)
    
    const roleMappings = await getGroupRoleMappings(master_token, group_id)
    console.log('roleMappings: ' + JSON.stringify(roleMappings))

    const optionalScopes = await getClientOptionalScopes(master_token, client_id)
    console.log(client_name +'\'s ' + 'optionalScopes: ' + JSON.stringify(optionalScopes, null, 4))

    const defaultScopes = await getClientDefaultScopes(master_token, client_id)
    console.log(client_name +'\'s ' + 'defaultScopes: ' + JSON.stringify(defaultScopes, null, 4))

    const scope_name = 'scope::group_a'
    const scopesMappings = await getScopesMappings(master_token)
    const scope_id = scopesMappings.find(item => item.name == scope_name)['id']
    console.log(scope_name  + '\'s ' + 'scope_id: ' + scope_id)

    const mappingGroup = await getScopeMappingGroup(master_token, scope_id)
    console.log(scope_name  + '\'s ' + 'assigned role: ' + JSON.stringify(mappingGroup, null, 4))
    
})()
```

To find `user_a`'s role -> it will be `role::group_a`

It will match `my-client` scopes and it's optional scopes list.
(scope::group_a and scope::group_b) and default scope (profile)

[image]

##### Conclusion

#1 `user_a' -> user access token -> get role
#2 client -> find scopes -> find assigned role

From #1 and #2 matched scope is the user's group scope.
The `user_a` 's scopes are `scope::group_a` and `profile`.

The `user_b` also will be find `scope::group_b` and `profile`.

Old version of Keycloak API in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75508151/keycloak-assign-a-client-scope-to-user-with-a-specific-role/75513974#75513974)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! So it's not possible to directly add scope to the access token fetch on http://localhost:8080/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token?  I mean I still have only "email profile" on scope claim. There is no way to append it to the claim from the groups?

Comment: If you set the client resource authorization, you can see the scopes in token in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72491613/how-to-import-client-authorization-settings-into-keycloak-realm-through-rest/72492860#72492860)