# In keycloak how do I add resources and scopes to the logged in user token?

Tags: jwt, authorization, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

#### In keycloak how do I add resources and scopes to the logged in user token?

I'm trying to do access control as follows. I add the admin role to user A, this role has access to the product resource and read and write scopes. In my system there is a part that I wanted to give access to to everyone who can read products.

I tried some things inside the client scope but it didn't work

Comment: you can see the resource role from access token in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75508151/keycloak-assign-a-client-scope-to-user-with-a-specific-role/75513974#75513974), but scope can't, scope can see by separate API in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76901216/keycloak-provide-scope-depending-on-the-group/76910660#76910660)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.